# How do I weight paint belts and straps?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

I have been attempting to weight paint the straps on this particular model for quite some time but have been unsuccessful in getting it to move naturally with the armature. I have approached the problem with the following techniques but have not found one that works well yet.

- Automatic weighting
- Transfer weight (Transfer mesh data)
- Weight Gradient
- Painting by hand

The straps tend to clip through the model when the hips are rotated and do not stay with the buckle.

Below is a few pictures of the model.
[image: Armature]
[image: Body]

Any advice on how to go about painting this or link to a tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the belts and the cute lil kitty one object? If not, you can always select the cute cat, shift select the belts, and ctrl j to join. Then weight paint it as normal.

Comment: What is this rig and character used for? I assume its not for a game because of the polycount? If you render the animation in Blender you  could include a shrinkwrap modifier below armature in the belt that would correct the clipping. Or try to simulate the belt with physics but perhaps that would be little backwards.

Comment: The cat is for a game, I'm trying to make it for the unreal engine but am having difficulty finding things out such as acceptable polygon count, what modifiers work ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem for shoulders straps. Three points here in my experience :

- Weight the buckle the same weights (uniformally)
- Weight the extremities of the straps the same as the buckle
- Space the next straps vertices at the first point of the cat shape they need to be "linked" to

Something like that https://gyazo.com/87bf0a45e2723b477d715645ae540be6
The idea is to keep the buckle linked to somekind of tangent point of the cat belly. And for the strap, to allow them to stretch between the buckle and the next "on skin" vertices.

Another way to obtain the result (maybe) is to shape all straps starting from the cat curves (using the knife tool probably : copy the cat and cut) so that you both keep the appropriate weights (from the cat) and also give all the good bending edges inside of the model. That can probably be easily done for the straps... but more difficult for the buckle.